# OS X/C++ - Cinder creates window that passes through keyboard input

Tags: c++, macos, input, cmake, cinder

[Cinder](https://libcinder.org/) is a graphics library which acts similar to a wrapper for `OpenGL` and `C++`.

Creating a basic application using the library's `CINDER_APP` function on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) and compiling with [XCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) works as expected: Pressing keys does nothing, as the application is not set up to handle keyboard input.

Using identical code and compiling with [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) gives a different result:: Key presses are passed through by the window, being handled by whatever application was last opened. This occurs even if the test application is set up to handle keyboard input. This makes it impossible to actually handle keyboard input in a window when compiling with CMake as keyboard inputs are passed through entirely as if the window does not exist.

To clarify, these two test applications are, in every visible way, identical: They use the same `.a` file of the library and the code is identical. **Necessary OS X Frameworks have been included** in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

What could be the cause of this issue? Some missing compiler flag in the `CMakeLists.txt` file? Some improper configuration of `CMake`? A slightly different standard library? The code clearly works, as evidenced by `XCode`, however there must be some way to compile it in `CMake` as well.